# Unable to have correct implementation for fscanf to read text file

Tags: c

I am writing a code in C to read a text file containing words followed by numbers in each line.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEIGHT 2
#define WIDTH  3

int main (void) {

#define MAX_WORDS 1000     /* Maximum words in a file */
#define MAX_VECTOR 500     /* Maximum length of vector */
#define WORD_LENGTH 100    /* Maximum length of a word */

    char words[MAX_WORDS][WORD_LENGTH];
    double numbers[MAX_WORDS][MAX_VECTOR];
    char ch, ch1;
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s%c", &words[i][j], &ch1) != EOF) {
        printf("line %d Read word %s \n", i, words[i]);
        while (!feof(fp) && (fscanf(fp, "%lf%c", &numbers[i][j], &ch) > 0)) {
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the text file I am reading from:

```
one 0.055901 -0.118006 0.165313 0.180452 0.026175 0.061411 0.066986 0.193535 -0.083337 -0.225704 -0.060372 0.052417 -0.158475 0.037001 -0.120630 0.033111 -0.120100 0.067668 0.008704 -0.011523 0.046506 0.049087 -0.008813 0.127401 0.046158 -0.042573 -0.069881 0.003825 -0.028860 0.240443 0.035992 0.224830 -0.090131 -0.119056 -0.110844 -0.111364 0.084449 0.140994 0.094664 0.075708 -0.133953 0.062725 0.059535 -0.058782 0.029325 -0.042819 -0.106856 0.061583 0.031914 0.306222 -0.110337 -0.309405 -0.114899 -0.010856 -0.014989 0.151228 0.096698 0.146314 -0.157354 -0.126845 0.066820 -0.073393 -0.154290 -0.052042 -0.203586 0.187294 -0.122756 0.017946 0.016923 0.017999 0.185696 0.177917 0.044500 -0.117416 -0.232413 0.108233 -0.119608 -0.007704 0.127663 -0.092061 0.175927 0.079500 0.041586 0.099287 -0.033317 -0.093927 -0.026158 0.135621 0.008939 0.000643 0.117516 -0.118172 -0.209071 0.204900 0.049810 -0.004155 0.062825 -0.106713 0.057214 0.160900
in 0.119589 -0.101502 0.157670 -0.056303 0.093967 -0.040834 -0.020207 0.137023 -0.039777 -0.219717 -0.158505 -0.039380 -0.175083 -0.157390 0.012432 -0.041457 -0.042300 0.145984 0.069490 -0.150424 -0.053245 0.114765 0.061037 -0.151042 -0.065063 0.018581 -0.124555 0.066553 -0.026960 0.077988 -0.082175 0.187142 -0.124159 -0.039581 -0.034646 -0.109485 -0.060480 -0.011689 0.056724 0.165933 0.122378 0.203326 -0.010104 -0.098575 0.137054 -0.088888 0.053554 0.109095 0.020053 0.041943 -0.102528 -0.121394 0.041362 0.082621 -0.123843 0.051251 0.200228 -0.039035 0.090276 -0.108120 -0.052834 -0.014503 -0.052226 0.048963 0.109746 0.021199 -0.032484 -0.105986 0.083844 0.255063 -0.073283 0.082236 -0.106431 -0.117873 -0.151227 0.070045 -0.124128 0.026318 0.065747 -0.084784 0.207990 0.032585 0.038751 0.006927 -0.087952 -0.007880 0.015686 0.084194 -0.004951 0.017214 0.046750 -0.015060 -0.052989 0.002429 -0.153604 0.140979 -0.059959 0.056583 0.094336 0.043655
the 0.067143 -0.085567 0.093489 -0.031480 0.088760 -0.114515 -0.073492 0.104196 -0.044105 -0.164238 -0.042719 -0.009412 -0.038835 -0.167318 0.049335 -0.067349 0.033283 0.166929 0.117321 -0.153897 -0.050847 0.045416 0.099851 -0.194546 -0.206180 0.007511 -0.184491 0.004285 -0.063807 0.037658 -0.146942 0.199758 -0.028947 -0.044207 0.033893 -0.075525 -0.056374 0.039984 0.072331 0.118431 0.027936 0.151556 -0.080778 -0.072760 0.143183 -0.112461 -0.071912 0.093536 -0.071345 0.108646 0.046915 -0.206292 0.054857 0.190562 -0.098070 0.065259 0.075209 0.002478 0.103516 -0.120264 0.095588 -0.090496 -0.011566 -0.083615 0.059932 0.131636 0.018365 -0.034486 -0.002322 0.213339 -0.018544 -0.053778 -0.010300 -0.060720 -0.022378 0.003257 -0.074792 -0.016189 0.159581 -0.071515 0.079529 -0.002136 0.148633 0.063139 -0.022998 -0.003740 -0.184454 0.048515 -0.019371 0.049397 -0.060432 -0.011129 -0.041152 -0.031710 -0.074927 0.115143 -0.125259 0.068263 0.066361 0.093564
zero 0.234512 -0.121474 0.109792 0.170790 -0.045752 -0.071400 0.019738 0.158155 0.021511 -0.166053 -0.150880 -0.006694 -0.043727 0.093643 -0.097609 0.084147 -0.145428 -0.056139 0.028827 -0.093471 -0.044423 0.141048 -0.134931 0.221719 -0.016770 0.122846 -0.183889 -0.057073 -0.172779 0.309650 0.063630 0.149560 -0.095836 0.018020 -0.116167 -0.009918 0.111300 0.223023 0.157299 0.039720 -0.154298 0.043226 0.101416 -0.049199 0.048870 -0.045169 -0.156941 0.116830 0.173794 0.383597 -0.100274 -0.321975 -0.124036 0.023479 0.080748 0.046896 0.012085 -0.009434 -0.007503 -0.117414 0.179445 -0.094763 -0.151722 -0.060418 -0.226912 0.208830 -0.194392 0.042646 -0.008948 -0.085489 0.201878 0.262699 -0.038696 -0.048645 -0.217569 0.085613 -0.150584 -0.038554 0.088378 -0.171745 0.144290 0.032441 0.012133 0.043000 -0.189177 -0.082102 -0.081147 0.034110 0.085813 -0.005733 0.070215 -0.159489 -0.234402 0.187624 -0.011026 -0.060671 0.006454 -0.171911 -0.013589 0.156288
two 0.163218 -0.162495 0.107668 0.189965 0.021145 -0.059619 0.069969 0.227159 -0.104848 -0.211165 -0.097430 -0.036023 -0.167298 0.105771 -0.122580 0.073573 -0.120958 -0.052100 0.016527 -0.104523 -0.017716 0.130014 -0.138620 0.226781 -0.005818 0.040699 -0.133840 -0.113423 -0.079806 0.225052 0.038002 0.171414 -0.102285 -0.097279 -0.077814 -0.001372 0.128911 0.192054 0.172628 0.022217 -0.207471 -0.010214 0.075996 -0.160409 0.052846 -0.102724 -0.205455 0.078162 0.145891 0.244547 -0.100726 -0.285166 -0.109984 -0.010353 0.032096 0.055797 0.131779 -0.022093 -0.059075 -0.104025 0.065460 -0.079490 -0.158377 -0.059249 -0.161154 0.211828 -0.223842 0.000820 -0.020411 -0.022983 0.251198 0.203735 -0.023917 -0.043052 -0.172147 -0.031201 -0.103603 -0.040366 0.055646 -0.122588 0.192388 0.048838 0.070381 0.089683 -0.133047 -0.032403 -0.054312 -0.012779 0.056384 0.091236 0.061532 -0.155145 -0.129997 0.175614 0.017461 -0.028298 -0.058765 -0.081411 -0.072236 0.189735
of -0.001951 -0.015085 0.084471 0.040791 -0.009868 -0.168987 -0.067308 0.213923 -0.086569 -0.333235 -0.112222 -0.041374 -0.092798 -0.031317 -0.020553 0.014663 -0.007836 0.269409 -0.010085 0.015774 -0.012206 0.028835 -0.018442 -0.199499 -0.201803 -0.011843 -0.144433 0.049827 -0.070247 0.069916 -0.211196 0.241704 -0.012689 -0.004990 0.042760 -0.036157 -0.017820 0.074232 0.033176 0.157031 -0.000485 0.088111 -0.026371 -0.067741 0.142190 -0.244216 -0.179696 0.070536 -0.103531 -0.014362 0.032295 -0.175132 0.102773 0.071197 -0.059370 -0.053416 0.054228 0.029710 0.155319 -0.209673 -0.009975 -0.111585 0.075680 -0.038655 0.032363 0.098720 -0.017634 -0.089254 0.083416 0.113366 0.017834 -0.015202 -0.065379 -0.056012 -0.045715 0.062862 -0.014786 -0.054141 0.210261 -0.058731 0.136597 -0.082168 0.084586 0.167382 0.125936 0.000861 -0.224336 0.089994 -0.091892 0.073959 -0.052474 0.121917 -0.039723 -0.083876 -0.055097 0.118483 0.058847 0.065449 0.008484 0.234890
nine -0.010725 -0.135403 0.207712 0.113996 0.028221 0.044365 0.043820 0.104305 -0.110333 -0.261671 -0.077261 -0.002075 -0.166750 -0.076413 -0.108014 0.006192 -0.117700 0.062126 0.016570 0.084561 0.052687 0.008349 -0.009415 0.082214 -0.049914 0.029446 -0.044039 -0.002531 -0.153363 0.305136 0.108226 0.284866 -0.146100 -0.096593 -0.143897 -0.081603 0.109941 0.101400 0.013379 0.016425 -0.068308 0.108234 -0.026083 0.041452 0.007674 -0.048208 0.006072 0.063190 0.114552 0.341608 -0.104171 -0.352664 -0.104702 -0.098595 -0.077682 0.103937 0.191864 0.227647 -0.090261 -0.122575 0.013941 -0.036474 -0.165873 -0.061009 -0.293947 0.181088 -0.133013 0.011490 0.049958 0.025505 0.142349 0.173667 0.007782 -0.252370 -0.266985 0.203502 -0.124187 0.022042 0.086614 -0.199419 0.210526 0.029766 -0.033012 0.014718 -0.079054 -0.108224 -0.109321 0.254357 -0.059781 -0.009854 0.126696 -0.143998 -0.226338 0.204981 0.079745 0.005007 0.116490 -0.141156 0.091475 0.146884
three 0.064841 -0.148413 0.144022 0.312825 -0.092667 0.010864 0.065698 0.167000 -0.045551 -0.224670 -0.076799 0.060682 -0.110617 0.144019 -0.137788 0.122421 -0.090556 0.041400 0.000787 -0.052565 0.080413 0.098228 -0.094225 0.209475 0.047809 0.037572 -0.119885 -0.052269 -0.024237 0.240604 0.006669 0.164075 -0.135630 -0.103809 -0.033470 -0.043257 0.076736 0.138235 0.103390 0.066088 -0.138050 0.011918 0.055177 -0.155095 0.085061 -0.064821 -0.170126 0.081735 0.096985 0.314806 -0.071335 -0.299790 -0.144218 -0.091587 0.010849 0.125377 0.149589 0.064134 -0.110915 -0.131961 0.063371 -0.109666 -0.215024 -0.035662 -0.185111 0.283482 -0.158863 0.064007 -0.031212 -0.057628 0.309444 0.236663 -0.029492 -0.082301 -0.244228 0.105325 -0.105852 -0.000318 0.088838 -0.121898 0.221658 0.150066 0.016648 0.172529 -0.075737 -0.043057 -0.047071 0.130021 0.024525 0.095203 0.064450 -0.119124 -0.197285 0.153680 0.012265 -0.087556 0.010506 -0.114373 0.014617 0.200275
and 0.015529 -0.036379 0.049296 -0.062052 0.021820 0.026468 -0.111432 0.007336 0.023165 -0.286446 -0.120580 -0.040351 -0.006140 -0.005968 0.108602 -0.010103 0.012874 0.209411 0.063205 -0.191001 -0.003015 0.107911 -0.097780 -0.073129 -0.008813 0.000912 -0.072629 -0.019062 -0.140533 0.017184 -0.162806 0.163511 -0.091244 0.059017 0.026109 -0.108640 0.055647 0.027877 0.010004 0.092852 -0.006883 0.016780 -0.077931 -0.046273 -0.036286 -0.180693 0.008362 0.024238 -0.021224 -0.042070 0.001111 -0.285467 0.025983 0.075629 -0.098480 0.006279 0.202481 -0.001996 0.036146 -0.152560 0.089948 -0.135093 0.028528 -0.076588 0.087000 0.177579 -0.012121 -0.119873 0.035132 0.184795 0.014542 -0.095826 -0.126894 -0.032745 -0.012016 0.106000 0.036118 -0.035248 0.046313 0.033656 0.204436 0.064991 0.108424 -0.044001 0.101860 -0.051185 -0.077767 0.140233 -0.157882 0.072773 0.160326 -0.019374 -0.059815 -0.080882 -0.025106 0.058795 -0.026581 -0.009323 0.011035 0.084858
four 0.118349 -0.162800 0.110744 0.340172 -0.022487 -0.019767 0.042030 0.161410 -0.112582 -0.209458 -0.053698 0.087612 -0.092919 0.162207 -0.174956 0.063242 -0.102680 0.032908 0.039262 0.011627 0.081248 0.076689 -0.088509 0.224808 0.023220 -0.024466 -0.136222 -0.075133 -0.104798 0.215218 0.053896 0.157784 -0.125113 -0.135654 0.011165 -0.054542 0.111526 0.119698 0.140533 0.052979 -0.181148 0.005903 0.028846 -0.113431 0.035944 -0.042162 -0.141869 0.104678 0.072759 0.316858 -0.036328 -0.327109 -0.169543 -0.054346 0.029164 0.120060 0.149542 0.109558 -0.074448 -0.124541 0.077755 -0.109614 -0.187328 -0.005012 -0.221655 0.236480 -0.149209 0.067970 -0.093467 -0.053515 0.280123 0.238634 -0.038969 -0.128666 -0.254481 0.167051 -0.065434 0.039131 0.118049 -0.172411 0.266380 0.086710 0.003595 0.140948 -0.055426 -0.056563 0.008428 0.130907 -0.011732 0.089420 0.123265 -0.174317 -0.246915 0.199815 0.001433 -0.088947 -0.004834 -0.053181 -0.002317 0.202105
five 0.079032 -0.124585 0.097004 0.315801 -0.041387 -0.000491 0.026458 0.131614 -0.040007 -0.225021 -0.043700 0.074494 -0.064386 0.130155 -0.181631 0.042613 -0.068803 0.050538 -0.011700 -0.019512 0.089360 0.118171 -0.154423 0.148352 0.056862 -0.001226 -0.123316 -0.011918 -0.092314 0.259075 0.088867 0.207309 -0.078464 -0.136953 -0.087909 -0.170365 0.098693 0.200012 0.156852 0.075736 -0.145202 0.064268 -0.008703 -0.002906 0.052095 -0.057744 -0.142530 0.096010 0.076482 0.301905 -0.122250 -0.330067 -0.200123 -0.042094 0.042398 0.105123 0.053732 0.076568 -0.045556 -0.096323 0.109578 -0.082138 -0.228469 -0.039445 -0.191996 0.229464 -0.094697 0.076695 -0.045100 -0.109369 0.266649 0.241430 0.019100 -0.108580 -0.295336 0.129930 -0.094996 -0.013525 0.135974 -0.189913 0.200923 0.068997 0.027637 0.122714 -0.123436 -0.077794 -0.019687 0.166606 0.050702 0.042525 0.176070 -0.151441 -0.233004 0.194048 0.028686 -0.090625 0.019997 -0.130009 0.040090 0.236055
```

And I get the following output:

```
line 0 Read word one 
line 1 Read word 0.119589 
line 2 Read word the 
line 3 Read word zero 
line 4 Read word two 
line 5 Read word of 
line 6 Read word ne 
line 7 Read word three 
line 8 Read word and 
line 9 Read word four 
line 10 Read word five
```

Clearly for line 1 the word read is incorrect (it is supposed to be `in` but instead it is a number). I am unable to understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing a very subtle problem:

Your test for the end of the sequence of numbers is failure to parse a number. At the end of the first line, `fscanf` skips the `\n` and attempts to parse the next number.  It consumes `in` because it is trying to match `inf` which is a valid number, namely +Infinity.  The matching fails when it reads the space character, but `fscanf` cannot unget more than one character, so the next *word* read will be the number `0.119589`.  If your file does not contain trailing spaces, here is a way to fix the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEIGHT 2
#define WIDTH  3

int main(void) {

#define MAX_WORDS 1000     /* Maximum words in a file */
#define MAX_VECTOR 500     /* Maximum length of vector */
#define WORD_LENGTH 100    /* Maximum length of a word */

    char words[MAX_WORDS][WORD_LENGTH];
    double numbers[MAX_WORDS][MAX_VECTOR] = { 0 };
    char ch;
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    int i, j;

    if (fp == NULL)
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS &&
                fscanf(fp, "%99s%c", words[i], &ch) == 2; i++) {
         printf("line %d Read word %s\n", i, words[i]);
         for (j = 0; j < MAX_VECTOR && 
                     ch != '\n' &&
                     fscanf(fp, "%lf%c", &numbers[i][j], &ch) == 2); j++) {
             continue;
         }
         /* ignore extra numbers on a line */
         while (ch != '\n' && (ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
             continue;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Also note that you are allocating 4.5 megabytes of automatic variables (aka on the stack).  This may fail on many systems.  Consider using global storage.

Comment: Thanks alot for the implementation, I was just wondering what is while statement doing. I tried running code without it and it is running fine.

Comment: @user3439142: as the comment says, the `while` loop is there in case there are more than `MAX_VECTOR` numbers on the line after the initial word.  It consumes any extra characters until it sees the end of line or the end of file.